# Hyperlink/link to cell where cell contains string

Tags: excel, hyperlink, cell, string-matching

I'm trying to dynamically link cells within Excel to allow for easy user navigation.

I currently have 3 different worksheets within a single document that contain different levels of "depth" within an information standard. I'd like to be able to create a reference (hyperlink/link) that allows users to navigate to the next level of depth from the higher point based on cell content. I'd like to do this in order to avoid updating static links to updated reference/s.

So, simply put, a high level cell would contain a string like "A-1", I want this cell to act as a link to a different worksheet that contains multiple cells about this "A-1" standard. So if we assume cell content as string variable ws1_cellA1 = "A-1" (worksheet 1, cell A1) the link would be something like a method:

return link(find_in_worksheet(worksheet=worksheet2, column=1, s1_cellA1))

This would enable me to edit the ws1 cell (ws1_cellA1) value and have the link to the subsequent worksheet2 column1 cell containing the cell value of s1_cellA1 dynamically update.

Any ideas on how I could go about achieving this?

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, you want to be able to edit one cell on your first worksheet and have it automatically update multiple cells on your other worksheets. Is that correct?

Comment: Not really. I want the cell to contain a dynamic link (based on a associated string value in a subsequent cell) that is automatically resolved. From a use perspective, I'm creating a document that outlines standards, and each link will provide a direct link to that standard's granular points. So if WS1 contains standard A-1, WS2 contains sub-standards A-1.A, A-1.B, etc. Ideally, the link would be resolved to all substandard cells because it contains string "A-1".